# I can't get my tizen web application to run in brackground

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I am developing a Tizen web application to retrieve heart rate data and send it to the Android application.
Everything works but sometimes the Tizen wearable goes to sleep and the data is no longer sent to the smartphone.

I already tried to add this in the **config.xml**: **<tizen:setting background-support="enable"/>**

and I also added this to my code: **tizen.power.request("CPU", "CPU_AWAKE");**

But when the smartwatch goes to sleep the application on it doesn't run anymore and the data is not sent to the phone anymore...

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is caused by the situation described [here](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/configuring-your-app/configuration-editor?langredirect=1#mw_setting):

> Since Tizen 2.4, the system manages background processes more tightly. Even if the background-support attribute is set to enable, a Web application process can be suspended in the background.

To prevent this situation, probably you need to set additional property [*background-category*](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/configuring-your-app/configuration-editor?langredirect=1#mw_bg_category)

Comment: background-category is only for mobile and wearables. See: [Configuration Element Hierarchy](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/configuring-your-app/configuration-editor?langredirect=1#hierarchy)